# Create a filter on python pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to put a filter on my pivot table, therefore I want to only aggregate values on column F when column C is 'UGX".

I did this on the below code:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["B"], values=["F"],
                       columns=[df.D=="UGX"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

I got the below results:

```
                         F              
D             False         True 
B                                
0.0    0.000000e+00           NaN
1.0    5.803969e+07  3.313538e+09
2.0    4.293864e+11  6.584239e+11
4.0    4.849234e+10  1.457356e+11
5.0    6.609481e+10  2.478473e+11
6.0    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
10.0   1.108451e+10  1.288109e+10
13.0  -3.000000e+10 -3.000000e+10
14.0   7.115493e+08  2.473186e+09
15.0            NaN  0.000000e+00
17.0   1.969734e+07           NaN
18.0   1.477040e+11  0.000000e+00
```

I only want to see the values under the "True"

Please assist.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you give a sample of your input dataframe which we can use to test solutions?

Comment: Instead of passing the full df as the first parameter in `pd.pivot_table` filter the df to  only where column C is 'UGX' and pass that as the first parameter in pivot_table.   `table = pd.pivot_table(df[df.D == 'UGX'], values=....`

Comment: hello, it worked, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the full df as the first parameter in pd.pivot_table filter the df to only where column C is 'UGX' and pass that as the first parameter in pivot_table. Let's try:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df[df.D == 'UGX'], values=["F"], columns=[df.D=="UGX"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```